# Zxing Camera in Portrait mode on Android

Tags: android, zxing, landscape-portrait

I want to show `portrait` orientation on `Zxing`'s camera.

How can this be done?

Comment: [Here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007194/how-to-use-zxing-in-portrait-mode/51784543#51784543)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Here's how it works.

**Step 1: Add following lines to rotate data before `buildLuminanceSource(..)` in *decode(byte[] data, int width, int height)***

**DecodeHandler.java:**

```
byte[] rotatedData = new byte[data.length];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        rotatedData[x * height + height - y - 1] = data[x + y * width];
}
int tmp = width;
width = height;
height = tmp;

PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = activity.getCameraManager().buildLuminanceSource(rotatedData, width, height);
```

---

**Step 2: Modify `getFramingRectInPreview()`.**

**CameraManager.java**

```
rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
```

---

**Step 3: Disable the check for Landscape Mode in `initFromCameraParameters(...)`**

**CameraConfigurationManager.java**

```
//remove the following
if (width < height) {
  Log.i(TAG, "Display reports portrait orientation; assuming this is incorrect");
  int temp = width;
  width = height;
  height = temp;
}
```

---

**Step 4: Add following line to rotate camera in`setDesiredCameraParameters(...)`**

**CameraConfigurationManager.java**

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

---

**Step 5: Do not forget to set orientation of activity to portrait. I.e: manifest**

Comment: This is pretty good! although you're going from only supporting landscape to only supporting portrait, rather than both. This won't work for front cameras either, or the upside-down portrait orientation.

Comment: @SeanOwen Yes sir, you are right :) It just a very simple tweak on the library to have a portrait-only camera scanning.

Comment: for me it doesn't works. My view finder rectangle in landScape mode but the camera rotate in 180. what goes wrong?

Comment: The camera images are squashed/not in proportion after going portrait. It scans fine though. Any way to fix this?

Comment: this exception shows 

 FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Crop rectangle does not fit within image data.
:  at com.google.zxing.client.android.PlanarYUVLuminanceSource.<init>(PlanarYUVLuminanceSource.java:46)
:  at com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.CameraManager.buildLuminanceSource(CameraManager.java:275)
 at com.google.zxing.client.android.DecodeHandler.decode(DecodeHandler.java:80)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5523):  at com.google.zxing.client.android.DecodeHandler.handleMessage(DecodeHandler.java:54)

Comment: @Rohit How is it going now? DId you follow all the stesps?

Comment: @Roylee , hey thnks , it is working, i want to ask, can it work in both landscap and portrait according to sensor, please help if u can

Comment: @Rohit Do you meant if you could have both landscape and portrait? Not with this code snippet :)

Comment: @Rohit I haven't tried yet and I didn't touched this project for quite sometime. Are you able to find a solution in SO, maybe you could have opened a thread?

Comment: This rotates the camera etc but then it doesnt scan for me.

Comment: @RussellCargill Are you following the steps correctly? it works for others.

Comment: Yeah I followed them to the letter but it would never scan for me :S
I found a solution though. Don't rotate it haha! I'm using it for QR Codes so it works both ways so I shall just remove any text from the view and leave it at that! But thanks for the concern.

Comment: worked to me, although camera image is a bit out of aspect ratio (qrcode, nexus4)

Comment: I´m having problems when running in ldpi device (Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360), the camera image stays wrong... did anyone experienced this?

Comment: But qr code is not being scanned proper as landscape mode

Comment: This is outdated with current version of ZXing library

Comment: If it doers not scan after rotate, I suspect step 1 is not followed 
PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = activity.getCameraManager().buildLuminanceSource(rotatedData, width, height);

Remember to replace data with "rotatedData". The text at step 1 is a bit misleading. One could think to only add the code, not replace the data variable.

Comment: Very helpful, since I'm still holding on to ZXing v2.2 for legacy compatibility.  I made it auto-detect the orientation -- instead of hard-coding portrait mode, I verify that the orientation is Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT before performing these alternate operations.  I also implemented a rotation calculation method as described in the comments for Camera.setDisplayOrientation().  Now I can rotate at will and the image appears correct (and it scans).

Comment: @Warpzit i just tried the 3.1.0 version, and couldn't see any convenient way to achieve portrait mode for barcodes

Comment: @Su-AuHwang Exacly, gotta work with legacy libs or set down spending hours to reverse engineer =/

Comment: @Warpzit what I meant was: I don't see how this answer is outdated. It still works on 3.10 and 3.10 still doesn't offer a more convenient way.

Comment: @Su-AuHwang Okay, I might've done something wrong, at least this fix didn't work for me with current version of ZXing library. The library has also been changed a lot since this was made.

Comment: my zxing version is 3.0.1, and the above changes seem do not apply to my case. I cannot have the camera in portrait mode. any helps? TIA

Comment: May I ask, for Step4, where should I put the code in?

Comment: @Derekyy CameraConfigurationManager.java

Comment: It works finally, but how could I change the dimension of the small rectangle inside the barcode scanner (the non-shady region)?

Comment: The image captured by camera is rotated by 90 degree while i am trying to scan. Like if you are clicking a photo of a person using the camera, then in my phone screen is showing the preview rotated by 90 degree. But that is not what i want as it is making bar code scanning difficult to use. I want preview as it should be. 

1) So 1st of all is it like that what you guys are getting it work too or i have done something wrong? 
2) If it is like so is there any way to make it normal user friendly?

Comment: need to fix findBestPreviewSizeValue() method in CameraConfigurationManager.java, too: find
      int maybeFlippedWidth = isCandidatePortrait ? realHeight : realWidth;
      int maybeFlippedHeight = isCandidatePortrait ? realWidth : realHeight;
and edit to:
      int maybeFlippedHeight = isCandidatePortrait ? realHeight : realWidth;
      int maybeFlippedWidth = isCandidatePortrait ? realWidth : realHeight;

Comment: If someone's looking for supporting both portrait and landscape mode, check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29504069/2128979

Comment: Hi, did you idea for zxing new version lib (3.0). it work with old version

Comment: @SameerZ. Unfortunately, not at the moment. It's been awhile since my last programming with zxing lib. Why not find out yourself and then post it here, if its correct, I will definitely mark it as answer :)

Comment: @Roylee https://github.com/xiaowei4895/zxing-android-portrait finally it is working

Comment: works well, but the yellow result points are not shown on the barcode.

Answer (score 7):

To support all orientation and change automatically when rotating the activity do this, all you have to modify is the **CameraManager.java**class.

And remove this method **getCurrentOrientation()** from **CaptureActivity.java**

**In CameraManager.java Create this variable:**

```
int resultOrientation;
```

**Add this to the openDriver(..) method:**

```
setCameraDisplayOrientation(context, Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, theCamera);//this can be set after camera.setPreviewDisplay(); in api13+.
```

****Create this method****
Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Context context,int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    Display display = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (display.getRotation()) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
    }


    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        resultOrientation = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        resultOrientation = (360 - resultOrientation) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        resultOrientation = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(resultOrientation);
}
```

****Now modify getFramingRectInPreview()****

```
if(resultOrientation == 180 || resultOrientation == 0){//to work with landScape and reverse landScape
            rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.x;
            rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.x;
            rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.y;
            rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.y;
        }else{
            rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
            rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
            rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
            rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
        }
```

And modify this method **public PlanarYUVLuminanceSource buildLuminanceSource(..)**

```
if(resultOrientation == 180 || resultOrientation == 0){//TODO: This is to use camera in landScape mode
        // Go ahead and assume it's YUV rather than die.
        return new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data, width, height, rect.left, rect.top, rect.width(), rect.height(), false);
    }else{
        byte[] rotatedData = new byte[data.length];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                rotatedData[x * height + height - y - 1] = data[x + y * width];
        }
        int tmp = width;
        width = height;
        height = tmp;
        return new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(rotatedData, width, height, rect.left, rect.top, rect.width(), rect.height(), false);
    }
```

Comment: it breaks the scale ratio of the preview on some devices

Comment: @mustafa I believe that's why they don't support the rotation in their own version of the library.

Answer (score 5):

You can use my fork of zxlib https://github.com/rusfearuth/zxing-lib-without-landscape-only. I disabled landscape mode only. You can set landscape/portrait and see correct camera view.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` in `CameraConfigurationManager.java` worked for me.

Comment: where to make this change ?

Comment: i think we need to edit the source code of zxing am i right @Samit?

Answer (score 2):

for zxing 3.0, working lib https://github.com/xiaowei4895/zxing-android-portrait
for portrait mode

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think the best library only solution is this one ...

https://github.com/SudarAbisheck/ZXing-Orient

You can include it in build.gradle as a dependency of your project in maven format ...

```
dependencies {
  compile ''me.sudar:zxing-orient:2.1.1@aar''
}
```

Comment: This library does not work. Jsut does not scan, all I get is `QRCodeNotFoundOnCamImage`

Comment: @Siddharth thanks yes I've edited my answer for a different library that works well, in fact the same way as ZXing BarcodeScanner and BarcodeScannerPlus apps.

Answer (score 2):

Create AnyOrientationCaptureActivity and then override default CaptureActivity then it will work.

```
public void scanCode() {
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(CommonUtil.POSEIDON_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
    integrator.setCameraId(0);
    integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
    integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
    integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
    //Override here
    integrator.setCaptureActivity(AnyOrientationCaptureActivity.class);

    integrator.initiateScan();
}

//create AnyOrientationCaptureActivity extend CaptureActivity
public class AnyOrientationCaptureActivity extends CaptureActivity {
}
```

Define in manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".views.AnyOrientationCaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@style/zxing_CaptureTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"></activity>
```

Comment: captureactivity is a replacement of normal extends activity?

Answer (score 1):

This is supposed to be a synched version to the above solution

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/4b124b109d90ac2960078ce68e15a39885fc1b5b

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to @roylee's modification I had to apply the following to the `CameraConfigurationManager.java` in order to get best possible preview and QR code recognition quality

```
    diff --git a/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationManager.java b/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationManager.java
index cd9d0d8..4f12c8c 100644
--- a/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationManager.java
+++ b/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationManager.java
@@ -56,21 +56,24 @@ public final class CameraConfigurationManager {
     Display display = manager.getDefaultDisplay();
     int width = display.getWidth();
     int height = display.getHeight();
-    // We're landscape-only, and have apparently seen issues with display thinking it's portrait 
+    // We're landscape-only, and have apparently seen issues with display thinking it's portrait
     // when waking from sleep. If it's not landscape, assume it's mistaken and reverse them:
+    /*
     if (width < height) {
       Log.i(TAG, "Display reports portrait orientation; assuming this is incorrect");
       int temp = width;
       width = height;
       height = temp;
     }
+    */
     screenResolution = new Point(width, height);
     Log.i(TAG, "Screen resolution: " + screenResolution);
-    cameraResolution = findBestPreviewSizeValue(parameters, screenResolution, false);
+    cameraResolution = findBestPreviewSizeValue(parameters, screenResolution, true);//
     Log.i(TAG, "Camera resolution: " + cameraResolution);
   }

   void setDesiredCameraParameters(Camera camera) {
+    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
     Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

     if (parameters == null) {
@@ -99,7 +102,7 @@ public final class CameraConfigurationManager {
   Point getScreenResolution() {
     return screenResolution;
   }
-  
+
   public void setFrontCamera(boolean newSetting) {
     SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     boolean currentSetting = prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_FRONT_CAMERA, false);
@@ -109,12 +112,12 @@ public final class CameraConfigurationManager {
       editor.commit();
     }
   }
-  
+
   public boolean getFrontCamera() {
     SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     return prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_FRONT_CAMERA, false);
   }
-  
+
   public boolean getTorch() {
     SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     return prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_FRONT_LIGHT, false);
@@ -181,7 +184,14 @@ public final class CameraConfigurationManager {
       Camera.Size defaultSize = parameters.getPreviewSize();
       bestSize = new Point(defaultSize.width, defaultSize.height);
     }
+
+    // FIXME: test the bestSize == null case!
+    // swap width and height in portrait case back again
+    if (portrait) {
+        bestSize = new Point(bestSize.y, bestSize.x);
+    }
     return bestSize;
+
   }

   private static String findSettableValue(Collection<String> supportedValues,
```