# zxing camera portrait mode and landscape on android

Tags: android, eclipse, zxing, barcode-scanner, portrait

I have already integrated zxing library in my application. Now i want that zxing camera will work on both mode landscape as well as on portrait mode. now it is working on one mode only. Can somebody help me out how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I used **compyutech**'s answer, but there were some things missing. So, I'm putting everything required, here.

**1. CameraConfigurationManager :**
inside `initFromCameraParameters` method :

```
if (context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
}
```

also remove this code from same method :

```
    if (width < height) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Display reports portrait orientation; assuming this is incorrect");
        int temp = width;
        width = height;
        height = temp;
    }
```

**2. CameraManager :** `class variables`

```
private static final int MIN_FRAME_WIDTH = 340;
private static final int MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT = 240;
private static final int MAX_FRAME_WIDTH = 1200;
private static final int MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT = 675;
```

`getFramingRect` method :

```
public synchronized Rect getFramingRect() {
    if (framingRect == null) {
      if (camera == null) {
        return null;
      }
      Point screenResolution = configManager.getScreenResolution();
      if (screenResolution == null) {
        // Called early, before init even finished
        return null;
      }

        // Code added to enable portrait mode
        int width = MIN_FRAME_WIDTH;
        int height = MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT;
        if (context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            int tmp = 7 * screenResolution.x / 8; 
            width = (tmp) < MIN_FRAME_WIDTH ? MIN_FRAME_WIDTH : (tmp);

            tmp = 1 * screenResolution.y / 3;
            height = (tmp) < MIN_FRAME_WIDTH ? MIN_FRAME_WIDTH : ((tmp) > MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT ? MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT : (tmp));
            Log.d(TAG, "Customized code for portrait mode in getFramingRect executed (Piyush Merja) ");
        }else{
            // Original Code
            width = findDesiredDimensionInRange(screenResolution.x, MIN_FRAME_WIDTH, MAX_FRAME_WIDTH);
            height = findDesiredDimensionInRange(screenResolution.y, MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT, MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT);
        }
        // End

      int leftOffset = (screenResolution.x - width) / 2;
      int topOffset = (screenResolution.y - height) / 2;
      framingRect = new Rect(leftOffset, topOffset, leftOffset + width, topOffset + height);
      Log.d(TAG, "Calculated framing rect: " + framingRect);
    }
    return framingRect;
  }

  private static int findDesiredDimensionInRange(int resolution, int hardMin, int hardMax) {
    int dim = 5 * resolution / 8; // Target 5/8 of each dimension
    if (dim < hardMin) {
      return hardMin;
    }
    if (dim > hardMax) {
      return hardMax;
    }
    return dim;
  }
```

`getFramingRectInPreview` method :

```
public synchronized Rect getFramingRectInPreview() {
    if (framingRectInPreview == null) {
      Rect framingRect = getFramingRect();
      if (framingRect == null) {
        return null;
      }
      Rect rect = new Rect(framingRect);
      Point cameraResolution = configManager.getCameraResolution();
      Point screenResolution = configManager.getScreenResolution();
      if (cameraResolution == null || screenResolution == null) {
        // Called early, before init even finished
        return null;
      }

      // Code added to enable portrait mode
        if (context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
            rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
            rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
            rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
            Log.d(TAG, "Customized code for portrait mode in getFramingRectInPreview executed (Piyush Merja) ");
        }else{
            // Original code commented
            rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.x;
            rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.x;
            rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.y;
            rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.y;
        }
        // End
        framingRectInPreview = rect;//this was missing in compyutech's answer
    }
    return framingRectInPreview;
  }
```

**3. DecodeHandler :**

inside `decode` method :

```
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Result rawResult = null;

    // Code added to enable portrait mode
    if (activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        byte[] rotatedData = new byte[data.length];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                rotatedData[x * height + height - y - 1] = data[x + y * width];
        }
        data = rotatedData;
        int tmp = width;
        width = height;
        height = tmp;
        Log.d(TAG, "Customized code for portrait mode in decode executed (Piyush Merja) ");

    }//end

    PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = activity.getCameraManager().buildLuminanceSource(data, width, height);
```

**4. AndroidManifest.xml :**

remove orientation settings for `CaptureActivity`.

Answer (score 2):

Google this question.

I have used zxing zxing 2.3 and below solution worked for me.

1  In CameraConfigurationManager class, setDesiredCameraParameters Method add below code below pointed line

-> Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

```
 if (context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
 }
```

2  In CameraManager class, getFramingRect Method replace code as below

```
int width = MIN_FRAME_WIDTH; int height = MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT;
if (context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
   int tmp = 7 * screenResolution.x / 8; 
   width = (tmp) < MIN_FRAME_WIDTH ? MIN_FRAME_WIDTH : (tmp);                   
   tmp = 1 * screenResolution.y / 3;
   height = (tmp) < MIN_FRAME_WIDTH ? MIN_FRAME_WIDTH : ((tmp) > MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT ?  MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT : (tmp));
}else{
   // Original Code
   width = findDesiredDimensionInRange(screenResolution.x, MIN_FRAME_WIDTH, > MAX_FRAME_WIDTH);
   height = findDesiredDimensionInRange(screenResolution.y, MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT,  MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT); 
}
```

3  In CameraManager class, getFramingRectInPreview Method replace code as below

```
if (context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
   rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
   rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
   rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
   rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
}else{
   // Original code commented
   rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.x;
   rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.x;
   rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.y;
   rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.y;
}
```

4  In DecodeHandler class, decode Method add below code below pointed line

-> Result rawResult = null;

```
 if (activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        byte[] rotatedData = new byte[data.length];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                rotatedData[x * height + height - y - 1] = data[x + y * width];
        }
        data = rotatedData;
        int tmp = width;
        width = height;
        height = tmp;

  }
```

Please find my working code

http://www.compyutech.co.in/repo/zxing-dynamic.zip

Hope this will help you....