# Zxing barcode reader portrait mode not working

Tags: android, layout, zxing

I have been searching on the internet for quite a few days to find a solution to rotate zxing scanner to portrait mode. Yet, the result is not satisfactory.
I have followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252791/zxing-camera-in-portrait-mode-on-android/16252917#16252917).

Yet my problem is, my scanner's custom layout did not rotate, but only the image captured is rotated. 
My question is how can I make the custom layout to rotate to portrait mode? Do I have to do it in xml? I tried adding a line - android:rotation="90" , but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it. It is my library's fault. I switched the library and repeat again, and it works.