# How to fix zxing in portrait mode?

Tags: android, camera, zxing

i using Zxing library 2.3 for barcode scanning. 
i decide to use this in portrait mode. then i use [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252791/zxing-camera-in-portrait-mode-on-android)  .
but the screen still in landscape and picture in portrait.
like the screen shot:
(in this pictures mobile is in portrait mode)
[image]
[image]
how to fix that?

Comment: Problem is Solved.  the screen orientation is not set to portrait in manifest. i set that and use [this](https://gist.github.com/border/7577978)  help and its work correct.