# Zxing (v3.2.0) Camera fixed portrait mode using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, zxing, landscape-portrait, portrait

I follow the instruction step by step on  [Zxing Camera in Portrait mode on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252791/zxing-camera-in-portrait-mode-on-android) to display portrait while user's using zxing camera.

But it won't work. The scanner is still appeared in the landscape mode.
I think it's because i am using the latest version **(v3.2.0)** of Zxing and the instruction is deprecated.

How can this be done in v3.2.0 Zxing?

---

*Anyway, Here are the steps I've tried:*

1. Modify buildLuminanceSource(..) DecodeHandler.java

Code:

```
byte[] rotatedData = new byte[data.length];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
         rotatedData[x * height + height - y - 1] = data[x + y * width];
}
int tmp = width;
width = height;
height = tmp;

PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = activity.getCameraManager().buildLuminanceSource(rotatedData, width, height);
```

---

2. Modify getFramingRectInPreview() in CameraManager.java

Code:

```
rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
```

---

3. Modify initFromCameraParameters(...) in CameraConfigurationManager.java

   In Zxing (v3.2.0), I don't find the following code

Code:

```
//remove the following
if (width < height) {
Log.i(TAG, "Display reports portrait orientation; assuming this is incorrect");
int temp = width;
width = height;
height = temp;
}
```

---

4. Add following line to rotate camera in setDesiredCameraParameters(...) in CameraConfigurationManager.java

Code:

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

---

5. In my project, modify AndroidManifest.xml

Code:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing trials and errors for couple days, here's my working solution:

It needs extra work, let's say Step 6. Always set the portrait orientation no matter what. And it worked.

---

Step 6.
Modify onResume in **CaptureActivity.java**

```
if (prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_DISABLE_AUTO_ORIENTATION, true)) {
  //setRequestedOrientation(getCurrentOrientation()); // mark this line
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
} else {
  //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);  // mark this line
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```